# How to toggle a theme in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to implement a button to toggle between light and dark. I  have a file AppRouter which looks something like this..

```
const theme = getTheme(true);
const AppRouter = () => {
   return (
          <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
              <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                 ...
                 <Switch> *all my routes are here including AppRoot, which routes to components* </Switch>
          </MuiThemeProvider></ThemeProvider>
);
}
```

So when i set getTheme(true) it triggers the dark theme, and getTheme(false) triggers the light theme. Here comes the problem, I would like to insert a toggle button into one of the components which is inside `Switch` that can allow user to switch between these two themes. Essentially, the component will be controlling the state of AppRouter. Is it possible?

Any idea where I could start from? I am using react hooks and type script. I have tried various methods to no avail. Would reducer work?

Update:

**AppRouter.tsx**

```
const [lightTheme, setLightTheme] = React.useState(true);
const theme = getTheme(lightTheme);
const AppRouter = () => {
   return (
          <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
              <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                 ...
                 <Switch> 
                     <PrivateRoute path="..." component={AppRoot} render{()=> <PageTitle toggleTheme={() => toggleTheme}/>}
                 </Switch>
          </MuiThemeProvider></ThemeProvider>
);
}
```

**PageTitle.tsx**

```
interface PageTitleProps {
  ...
  toggleTheme?: () => void;
}

const PageTitle: React.FC<PageTitleProps> = ({ ... toggleTheme}) => {
  ...
  return ( 
  ... 
  {toggleTheme && <Button OnClick={() => toggleTheme()}>Change Theme</Button>
)}
```

I have tried running the code above, but toggleTheme is undefined - so the button does not show up at all. 
toggleTheme has to be optional.

Comment: Create a local state inside the AppRouter and pass the setter down to the Route component you wish to toggle the theme. Let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: How do I pass setter down the Route component? Is there a link where i can refer? 

Inside switch, i have <PrivateRoute component={AppRoot}/>. This is not where i want the toggle button to be.

Comment: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-components/

Comment: I’m using typescript and react hooks. I tried doing const [theme, setTheme] = React.UseState(getTheme(true)). How should i get setTheme to work from another component? I’m confused as heck.

Answer (score 1):

Create a local state inside your AppRouter and pass down the toggler to the component(s) that will toggle the theme.

AppRouter.tsx:

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react';

 const AppRouter = () => {
 const [lightTheme, setLightTheme] = useState(true);
 const theme = getTheme(lightTheme);
 const toggleTheme = () => setLightTheme(!lightTheme);
 return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
             ...
             <Switch> 
               <Route path='your-path' render={(props) => 
                 <PageTitle toggleTheme={ toggleTheme } />} />
             </Switch>
       </MuiThemeProvider></ThemeProvider>
 );
 }
```

PageTitle.tsx:

```
interface PageTitleProps {
  ...
  toggleTheme?: () => void;
}

const PageTitle: React.FC<PageTitleProps> = ({ ... toggleTheme}) => {
  ...
  return ( 
  ... 
  <button onClick={() => toggleTheme()}>Change Theme</button>
)}
```

Comment: It doesnt do anything for me. How do i get the values? Let me know if i did it wrongly. So i have a component PageTitle, i did <Route component={AppRoot} render=(() => <PageTitle toggleTheme={() => alert(“hello”)}/>. In my PageTitle I did a const PageTitle: React.FC<PageTitleProps> = ({toggleTheme}) => {...}

Comment: Update your question with the code you have, please. But essentially, you need to call the toggleTheme function somehow inside your component. Try to log the function to see if it is being passed down.

Comment: The alert I am trying to do is to see if i am getting any values from toggleTheme, which does not appear so.

Comment: toggleTheme doesn't return any value. It return a function that sets the state to true or false. Call the function like this <button onClick={()=>toggleTheme()} >Change theme</button>

Comment: Hi LuisMendes, sorry for the trouble. I have updated my codes above, are you able to help me? It seems like the buttons is undefined, how do should i define it?

Comment: 2 things, you need to update the AppRouter.tsx with the code I wrote up above and second use button with lower case. You want to use <button/> , the HTML tag. Also, onChange and not OnChange. And you need to import useState in the AppRouter.tsx too if you didn't already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214004/discussion-between-luismendes535-and-joey-peh).